# How to avoid OOM when working with byte arrays and Bitmaps in Android

Tags: java, android, android-glide

I'm making a simple Android chatting app that can send images and text. I'm temporarily using a MySQL database in localhost, in which I store the base64 string of the image (I need to do this because I have to display the image in a web version of the chat too). So far the web version works just fine, but my Android app runs into OOM every 2-3 pictures sent.

Here's my code for converting the base64 into a Bitmap and displaying it with Glide, which I put in a RecyclerView Adapter to display images sent in the chat:

```
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(c.getMessage(), Base64.DEFAULT);
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
options.inSampleSize=16;
decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length,options);
Glide.with(viewHolder.mymessageImage.getContext())
                        .asBitmap()
                        .load(decodedString)
                        .thumbnail(0.5f)
                        .into(viewHolder.mymessageImage);
decodedString=null;
```

And these are the errors I got:

```
E/dalvikvm-heap: Out of memory on a 4205580-byte allocation.
E/GlideExecutor: Request threw uncaught throwable java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
```

I'm using Glide because formerly, I was using

```
viewHolder.mymessageImage.setImageBitmap(decodedByte);
```

to display the images and it resulted in OOM too. The error when I directly setImageBitmap was OOM at the

```
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(c.getMessage(), Base64.DEFAULT);
```

line. After some Googling, a lot of people said Glide would be the solution. Glide did help with the loading speed but it still crashes with OOM after sending 2-3 pictures and scrolling the RecyclerView up and down several times.

I've tried to fix this issue for a week to no avail. I'm pulling my hair out thinking about this. Please help me find a solution to make my app run smoothly without OOM.

Comment: Did you read this tutorial? https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/

Comment: @Prexx I have, that's where I got the idea to use Glide from